# Integrity constraint violation when inserting data in HSQLDB

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, unit-testing, hsqldb

I'm using HSQLDB + Hibernate to run some unit tests for an application I'm developing. I have a test that persists an entity with three OneToOne relation with others entities. When I run the test using MySql I have no errors and the test pass, but when I run the same test against HSQLDB I get a **java.sql.SQLException: Integrity constraint violation - no parent FK_...** being the FK_ one of the foreign keys defined in the relations of the Person class.

My code is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long oid;
    private Address commercialAddress;
    private Address homeAddress;
    private Settings settings;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "OID")
    public Long getOID() {
        return this.oid;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ADDRESS_OID", nullable = false)
    @ForeignKey(name = "FK_PERSON__COMPANY_ADDRESS")
    public Address getCommercialAddress() {
        return this.commercialAddress;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "HOME_ADDRESS_OID", nullable = false)
    @ForeignKey(name = "FK_PERSON__HOME_ADDRESS")
    public Address getHomeAddress() {
        return this.homeAddress;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SETTINGS_OID", nullable = false)
    @ForeignKey(name = "FK_PERSON__SETTINGS")
    public Settings getSettings() {
        return this.settings;
    }
}
```

Address and Settings classes has no relations, they are simple hibernate entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address {
    private Long oid;
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private String province;
    private String postalCode;
    private String street;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "OID")
    public Long getOID() {
        return this.oid;
    }

    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Settings")
public class Settings {
    private Long oid;
    private String backgroundColor;
    private String fontName;
    private Integer fontSize;
    private String themeName;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "OID")
    public Long getOID() {
        return this.oid;
    }

    ...
}
```

I performed several searches using google and I couldn't find something useful. Hope someone can point me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance.